# Godaddy Hosting HTTP GET Request Lengh Issue

Tags: php, http, url, get

I am facing a difficulty receiving the full length of a request in PHP file. I have written a sample like this.

1. Wrote a test.php file with below content,

   ```
   <?php
   $data = $_GET['data'] ;
   echo($data);
   ?>
   ```
2. Now I have checked this with the browser with the following URL,

   ```
   http://myserver.com/test.php?data=DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
   ```
3. I have tested this by increasing the number of D letters increased to see how much data can be passed maximum.
4. What I found was only 478 characters were received and shown in the echo statement. When I put more letter 'D' s in the parameter it won't show.
5. What I gathered was maximum of 512 characters can be received. If the total length is more that that it won't pass the get parameter. (will result empty data). I changed the browser but the effect is same.
6. But this same thing work perfectly well with my localhost (WAMP server) with Firefox, Chrome etc and can send / receive largeer request data. I understand this is not a browser issue but the server has a limit. (My GET Requests are about 1000 characters long in average and did not work in the godaddy server).
7. I am using GoDaddy shared hosting server. I guess this can be solved if I can increase the request length allowed at GoDaddy Server. But don't know if this is possible also.

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Session variables?

Comment: Noticeable effort for a first question in SO. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
// in the sending page:
session_start();
$_SESSION["data1"] = $data1;
$_SESSION["data2"] = $data2;


// in the recieving page:
Session_start();
$data1 = $_SESSION["data1"];
$data2 = $_SESSION["data2"];
```

As far as I know session variables has no limits in size.
The only drawback is that the users can't bookmark or share the results with someone else

Comment: Dear Anreas Thanks for the effort, What I need is not to pass from PHP page to page. Those are request variables passed from the client side. For example I have an ajax GET request which has long encrypted parameter data (single get variable).